# Drupal 6: CCK computed field confusing error

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, cck

I've been using `Computed field` CCK plugin to calculate the members's age.

The code is presented below and I'm getting confusing error `...computed_field/computed_field.module(161) : eval()'d code on line 6`.

What may cause this error, what am I missing here?

```
if (!$node->nid) node_save($node);

$dob = $node->field_dob[0]['value'];

if(!$dob || empty($dob)) {
    $node_field[0]['value'] = 'N/A';
} else {
    $dob = $node->field_dob[0]['value'];
    $now = time();
    $then = strtotime($dob);
    $diff = date('Y', $now) - date('Y', $then);
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Sultan

Comment: Did you use PHP code when setting the field's properties? this usually happens when Drupal needs to generate available values for a field, but the PHP code is wrong

Comment: I put this code into a `Computed Code` inside of `Global settings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$node_field[0]['value'] = 'N/A';
```

change to:

```
$node->field[0]['value'] = 'N/A';
```

Comment: and according to an official doc `$node_field[0]['value']` should be

Comment: maybe it should be $node->field_dob[0]['value'] = 'N/A'; ?

Comment: Hi folks, I've figured things out. The code is clear, but the problem was the code indentations.